# What is the dimension of this Grassmannian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Why is  $2\times 3$ the dimension of $Gr_2(\mathbb{R}^5)$? and can one use the dimensions of Lie groups to derive this dimension?

Note: $Gr_2(\mathbb{R}^5)$ denotes the [Grassmannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) of all $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: Thanks for any helpful answers!

Comment: I've edited your question, I hope it is ok.

Comment: The top dimensional cell in $Gr_2(\Bbb{R}^5)$ consists of matrices of the (reduced row echelon) form
$$\pmatrix{1&0&*&*&*\cr0&1&*&*&*\cr}.$$ Six asterisques - a six-dimensional cell. The interpretation here is that I equate a 2-d subspace with a matrix having that space as its rowspace. All row equivalent matrices share the same row space, so if you use reduced row echelon form you get one of each.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest proof is this: to give a $k$-plane in $\mathbb R^n$ you must give a $k \times n$-matrix $M$, hence $kn$ variables. But this is only unique up to multiplication by invertible $k \times k$-matrices, so you must subtract $k^2$. Hence the dimension is $kn-k^2=k(n-k)$. In your case, it is $2 \cdot (5-2)=2 \cdot 3$.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. We cannot choose any $k$x$n$ matrix, because it must have rank $k$. We also cannot choose any $k$x$k$ matrix, because it has to be invertible. The difference $nk-k^2$ gives the right answer, but it looks like the argument is incorrect.

Comment: @AguirreK You are right that we cannot chose any $k \times n$-matrix, but the set of rank $k$ matrices is dense in the set of all $k \times n$-matrices, so the dimensions are correct.

Answer (score 7):

Let $V$ be a real finite dimensional vector space and choose some basis $(e_i)_{i=1}^n$ for $V$. Given $I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}$, denote by $J$ the set $J = \{1, \ldots, n\} \setminus I$ and set $V_I = \mathrm{span} \{ e_i \}_{i \in I} \subseteq V$. One way to give $\mathrm{Gr}_k(V)$ the structure of a smooth or topological manifold is to cover it with (what will become) charts $\phi_I \colon \mathrm{GL}(V_I,V_J) \rightarrow \mathrm{Gr}_k(V)$ defined by
$$ \varphi_I(L) = \mathrm{graph}(L) = \{ v + L(v) \, | \, v \in V_I \} \subseteq V $$
where $I$ is a subset of cardinality $k$.

As $\dim GL(V_I,V_J) = k(n-k)$, this shows that $\dim \mathrm{Gr}_k(V) = k(n-k)$. One can use the set-theoretic maps $\varphi_I$ to define the topology and smooth structure of $\mathrm{Gr}_I(V)$ or use a different method to endow $\mathrm{Gr}_I(V)$ with a topology and smooth structure (such as interpreting $\mathrm{Gr}_I(V)$ as quotient space) and then show that in fact the maps $\varphi_I$ are charts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you use Lie groups to derive the dimension in general ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, just repeat johndoe's argument with $5$ replaced by $n$ and $2$ by $k$. I wanted to show this from a non-quotient point of view.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that by $Gr_2(\mathbb{R}^5)$ you mean the Grassmannian of 2-planes in $\mathbb{R}^5$. By introducing an inner product in $\mathbb{R}^5$ you can pass to orthogonal frames and deduce the isomorphism $Gr_2(\mathbb{R}^5)\simeq O(5)/(O(2)\times O(3))$, from which you get the answer.

Comment: But the dimension of $O(k)$ is $k(k-1)/2$, then how to get $2\times3$? Thanks!

Comment: There's a typo in johndoe's solution. The numerator of his homogeneous space should be $O(5)$, not $O(2)$. So the dimension of the quotient space is $5\cdot 4/2 - \big(1 + 3\cdot 2/2\big) = 10-4 = 6$.

Comment: yes you're right, typo corrected.