# How can we parametrise this matricial hypersphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, random-matrices

What I call a *matricial hypersphere* for lack of a recognised name is the set in $\mathbb{R}^{p\times k}$ defined by
$$\mathfrak{H}=\left\{
a_1,\ldots,a_k\in \mathbb{R}^{p};\ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i a_i^\text{T} = \mathbf{A}
\right\}$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $p\times p$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix of rank $k$ $(k\le p)$. My questions are

1. Is this a well-known object?
2. Given the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is there a completion of $\mathbf{A}$ into an object in bijection with $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$, which is my meaning of *parameterisation*?
3. what is the size or dimension of $\mathfrak{H}$?

> **Note:** This object does not stem out of nowhere. It appears in linear
>   regression, where the $a_i$ vector is a collection of regression
>   coefficients,  and in connection with Wishart distributions, where the
>   $a_i$'s are Normal variates. I actually need to find a
>   reparameterisation of the $a_i$'s given $A$ to proceed a research
>   problem.

Comment: I don't understand: the product $a_ia_i^T$ is a scalar and not a square matrix of order $p$!

Comment: In your notation: $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^p$, that is you are considering a row vector with $p$ entries, therefore $a_ia_i^T\in\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: You seem to have given a lot of thought to this object but include so few details. The entire post seems rushed and lacking of care. It's a shame

Comment: I think this is a pretty well-defined question. Naturally, we are assuming that, as is usually taken to be the standard, elements of $R^p$ are _column_ vectors, hence $aa^T$ is a $p$ times $p$ matrix. No problems there. Given what the OP asks, I couldn't possibly see what extra "details" or "care" could / should be expected to be put into this, other than maybe some slight context to understand from where this question originated. Nevertheless, I unfortunately haven't encountered anything like this before, but I really like the question. (Or, well, $p=1$ gives a sphere, so that's one down…)

Comment: @DavidP The word "shame" should be used in more dramatic cases...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Point 1) Let $B$ be the matrix with columns $a_i$: your description is equivalent to

$$\tag{1}BB^T=A$$

Thus, being given a symmetrical semi-definite positive $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with rank $k$, $\frak{H}$ can be identified with the set of $n \times k$ matrices $B$ such that $A$ can be written under the form (1).

**Remark:** formula (1) is "up to the multiplication by a $k \times k$ orthogonal matrix $\Omega$" (with property $\Omega\Omega^T=I_k$). More precisely, any decomposition of the form (1) generates a family of decompositions:

$$\tag{2}B\Omega\Omega^TB^T=A \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ B'B'^T=A \ \ \text{with} \ \ B':=B\Omega$$

Point 2): Concerning parameterization, couldn't you use the more or less classical parametrizations of the (grassmannian) manifold of $k$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{R^n}$ ? A reference (http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/schubertcalculusreview.pdf). Let us take an example with $n=3$ and $k=2$ :

$$B^T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&x\\0&1&y\end{pmatrix}$$

(I have taken $B^T$ because the "landscape" form is easier to work with).

The idea behind this parameterization which places into evidence a first block $I_k$ is this one :

Consider $B^T$, which is rank-$k$ matrix with $k$ rows and $n$ columns.

We can write it under the block form $B^T=(C|D)$ where $C$ is square.

By multiplying it (in the same spirit as in (2) by $C^{-1}$, one obtains $(I_k|E)=(I_k|C^{-1}D)$ ;

As a partial conclusion, matrices $B$ such that $B^TB=A$ correspond in a bijective way to k-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$, thus can be parameterized in the same way as them, using $k \times (n-k)$ parameters.

Point 3) Consequently, $\frak{H}$ considered as a **manifold** (it is evidently not a vector space), has dimension $k(n-k)$. See for example Stack Exchange question ([What is the dimension of this Grassmannian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/598331)).

Another reference linked to statistical applications: (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis515/Turaga_Stiefel_2011.pdf).

Comment: I have modified my answer in order to include point 3 as well.

Comment: The argument is uniquely aimed at finding the number of degrees of freedom (which amounts to the dimension of the variety) of matrices $B^T$, not for finding another explicit general form of elements of $\frak{H}$.

Comment: See the remark I have placed close to the beginning.