# How many numbers to describe a subspace of a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

What is the minimum number of numbers to describe a generic subspace of dimension $n$ of a vector space of dimension $d$?

---

Here are some attempts.
For example, consider $d=4$.

- To describe a point, I need zero numbers.
- To describe a one-dimensional subspace, I need at most $4-1 = 3$ numbers (e.g. a unit vector
  living on the line describing the one-dimensional subspace). The constraint of unit normalization reduces the number of numbers required by one.
- To describe a two-dimensional subspace, I need at most $(4-1) + (4-1) - 1 =5$ numbers. The two $(4-1)$ refer to two orthogonal unit vectors forming a basis for the two-dimensional space, and the last $-1$ is because the unit vectors are orthogonal. I'm unsure if this is the minimum number of numbers needed to describe a two-dimensional subspace of a four-dimensional space.
- To describe a three-dimensional subspace, I believe I only need to describe a unit vector perpendicular to that subspace. This leaves us with $4-1 = 3$, the same as the one-dimensional case.
- To describe the whole space, I need zero numbers.

---

More generally, building off the idea of creating an orthogonal basis for the subspace of interest (or building an orthogonal basis for the subspace orthogonal to the subspace of interest), I expect that the result will be $$f(n,d) = dn - \frac{1}{2}n(n+1) \text{ for } n<\frac{d}{2}$$ and $f(d-n, d)$ otherwise. However, I'm left wondering if I can make do with fewer numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $n$-dimensional subspaces of a $d$-dimensional vector space $V$ would form a vector space, then what you are looking for would be its dimension.

Even though that is not the case, if $V$ is a real vector space the space $n$-dimensional subspaces does carry the structure of a smooth manifold, which is called the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $\operatorname{Gr}(n, V)$.

Its dimension is given by $n(d-n)$.

For example, $\operatorname{Gr}(2,\mathbb{R}^4)$ has dimension $2(4-2) = 4$ (in your description with $5$ numbers, you have one "superfluous" degree of freedom which is the choice of the orthogonal basis).

| $n$ | dimension of $\operatorname{Gr}(n, \mathbb{R}^4)$ |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0(4-0) = 0$ |
| $1$ | $1(4-1) = 3$ |
| $2$ | $2(4-2) = 4$ |
| $3$ | $3(4-3) = 3$ |
| $4$ | $4(4-4) = 0$ |

See also this related question for some geometric explanation:

[What is the dimension of this Grassmannian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598331/what-is-the-dimension-of-this-grassmannian)

Comment: The vocabulary of "Grassmannian" is extremely helpful! The linked dimension counting arguments are also helpful.